# Appending random number on File I/O

Tags: python

I am having trouble with a really simple problem. Trying to write a program to give a random number and append on a txt file and write unique number every time.

```
i = 0
num = 0

while (0<=num<=10 and i<1):
    with open ('Rajdhani.txt', 'r') as f:
        a = f.read()
        lines = a.split()
    num = random.randint(1,10)
    if (lines != num):
        with open('Rajdhani.txt', 'a') as f:
            f.write(f"\n{num}")
            print(num)
            i = i + 1
    elif (lines == num):
        print(f"{num}the number was same as txt")
```

The code is adding duplicate number on txt file also. Please help!

Comment: `lines` is a list of string and `num` is a number. so the if condition will always fail. Instead of `lines != num` you should check if str(num) present in lines. Like `if str(num) not in lines`

Comment: Run the code in a debugger to step through it. If you don't know how, try to find a video tutorial for your IDE. That said, I'm not sure how your algorithm is supposed to work. Maybe if you described it in plain English it would help. As a new user here, please also take the [tour] and read [ask]. Further, make sure you provide a [mcve]: Your code is close, but can't be executed as it stands.

Comment: Conventionally (your file should already end with a newline and) you should add a newline _after_ the new information.

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing `lines` and `num`. `lines` is a `list` while `num` is an `int` so it does not make sense to compare these.

I have rewritten it as such, with a bit simpler logic:

```
with open ('Rajdhani.txt', 'r+') as f: # allows read and append
    lines = f.read().split()
    while True: # breaks when found unique num
        num = random.randint(1,10)
        num_string = str(num)
        if num_string not in lines: # if the number is unique
            f.write(num_string + '\n')
            break # stop loop
```

There are still some problems here - when all 10 lines are written, this program will continue forever.

You can simply solve this by checking the number of lines first:

```
with open ('Rajdhani.txt', 'r+') as f: # allows read and append
    lines = f.read().split()
    if len(lines) < 10:
        while True:
            num = random.randint(1, 10)
            num_string = str(num)
            if num_string not in lines: # if the number is unique
                f.write(num_string + '\n')
                break # stop loop
```

I tried converting `lines` to a `set` for faster searching, and it was consistently faster (10-15% with 500 numbers). As expected, this increase is lower when it's just 10 numbers, about 2% speed increase for me using `set`. With 10000 it is 150-200% faster to use `set`.

```
with open ('Rajdhani.txt', 'r+') as f:
    lines = set(f.read().split())
    if len(lines) < 10: # if possible to add unique number in range
        while True: # Must terminate eventually
            num = random.randint(1, 10)
            num_string = str(num)
            if num_string not in lines:
                f.write(num_string + '\n')
                break
```

Just in case you are trying to just insert 10 random unique numbers into a file, you can use:

```
numbers = list(range(1,11))
random.shuffle(numbers)
```

Then write each number as a string on a new line.

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing two different data types, a list of strings and an integer

If i understood correctly, what you meant to do is this:

```
i = 0
num = 0

while (0<=num<=10 and i<1):
    with open ('Rajdhani.txt', 'r') as f:
        a = f.read()
        lines = a.split()
    num = random.randint(1,10)
    if (str(num) not in lines):
        with open('Rajdhani.txt', 'a') as f:
            f.write(f"\n{num}")
            print(num)
            i = i + 1
    else:
        print(f"{num}the number was same as txt")
```

This is not the best way to achieve that tho, this is what I would do:

```
import random

added_numbers = open('Rajdhani.txt', 'r').read().split()

while len(added_numbers) < 10:

    rnd_num = str(random.randint(1, 10))

    # if the number is not already present, add it
    if rnd_num not in added_numbers:
        
        open('Rajdhani.txt', 'a').write(f"\n{rnd_num}")
        added_numbers.append(rnd_num)
```